Handling POST request form with Flask app and Google App Engine
I am working on my first web app using Flask as the backend but I am having some issues with a form with a POST request. The form works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it to GCPs app engine it does not work. Whenever I click the submit button for the form - the page just loads indefinitely.
When looking at the logs I do not even see a POST request go through. I added some debugging prints to the Flask code, and the one at the very start of the POST function does not show up in the logs. This makes me think it is something to do with how the form / POST request is set up.
Does anyone know whats going on? Do I have to do some CSRF stuff (saw that in another thread)? Is there something else I have to do when handling POST requests on App Engine? Maybe some configuration in the app.yaml file? I am pretty stumped because it doesn't look like the POST request is even going through so not sure where to keep looking.
Some more context: The app allows user to create a Spotify playlist from Spotify links sent in an iMessage group chat.
The bare bones of my form is below. It has a file input, text input, and a submit button.
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="chatTracksForm" class="playlist-form">
        <h2 class="mainHeaders">1. Upload file</h2>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".db" class="input-file">
      
        <h2 id="header2" class="mainHeaders">2. Enter name</h2>
        <input type="text" id="chat_name" name="chat_name" placeholder=" Group chat name">

        <input type="submit" value="Create Playlist" id="btnSub">
</form>

Here is the Flask code that handles the form submission. Cleaned up some the debugging print but otherwise this is pretty bare.
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def create_playlist():
    print("YO")
    cache_handler = spotipy.cache_handler.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(session)
    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(cache_handler=cache_handler)
    if not auth_manager.validate_token(cache_handler.get_cached_token()):
        return redirect('/')
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

    file = request.files['file']
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        output = file.save(filepath)

        chat_name = request.form['chat_name']
        playlist = PlaylistFromiMessage(sp, filepath)

        ##### CREATING PLAYLIST LOGIC ##### # Getting messages - if messages return 0 that means error with input chat_name
        messages = playlist.get_messages_from_groupchat(chat_name)
        if len(messages) == 0:
            error_message = f"No messages for {chat_name} - try another group chat"
            return render_template("create_playlist.html", error_message=error_message)

        # Creating playlist
        playlist_id = playlist.create_new_playlist_if_not_exists(chat_name)
        # Getting spotify ids for messages
        spot_ids = playlist.get_spotify_ids(messages)
        # Adding tracks to playlist
        tracks_added = playlist.add_tracks_to_playlist(playlist_id, spot_ids)

        # Return success page with link to spotify playlist
        playlist_obj = sp.playlist(playlist_id)
        spotify_playlist_link = playlist_obj["external_urls"]["spotify"]
        return render_template('success.html', playlist_url=spotify_playlist_link, tracks_added=tracks_added)

    else:
        return redirect('/')


What are the differences between your app.yaml locally and on the server?

What does the browser debugger (inspect) show under Console and Network tabs?

Here is the post request in the network tab when I submit the form: https://ibb.co/mS7Cwyj
I am not super familiar with networking stuff so not 100% sure what I am looking at.
And there is no difference between app.yaml. app.yaml just defines the python runtime and the other directories that are used.
Also I think this might be some important context - My PlaylistFromiMessage object is opening and querying a sqlite3 file, and using spotipy (spotify python sdk) to create a playlist. Not sure if any of these would cause problems when being hosted on app engine.

Please put the requested information in your question and not via comments. Do not use external links as they are often not available for future readers. The screenshot does not provide the requested information from the Console and Network tab. If that is confusing, invest the time to watch a video or two on how to use the browser inspect feature for debugging. That will save you lots of time in the future and make your apps much better/safer. Google Chrome for example will report useful information to help you improve your app


If you're saying the Flask code you've posted is going to handle your form submission, then add action = "/" to your form (see action attribute)

Since your code has only a POST method for this route, I assume you have a separate function to handle the GET, right? If you don't, then your code won't work because there's no function to handle your redirect to the / which is a GET call


UPDATES

Your print statement won't show up by default because of the way Google App Engine handles logging.
Switch to the logging module. Add the following to your code and then use logging.info("YO")
import logging

# Set the logging level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)



If you want to get a 'close-enough' behavior of your App locally, then you should run it using dev_appserver.py. At the minimum, it will run your App with app.yaml and some (not all) of the restrictions that Google App Engine production has



Yeah I am new to Flask / html and web apps in general so I think I missed that. Interesting thing is that the site worked as expected locally. Another think to note - on form submission, sometimes the post request shows up on the App Engine logs and sometime it doesn't. Not sure what is going on there. And tried adding the action attribute - still getting same result. Sent a link in the above comments with the POST request entry in the network tab also.

@DatBoi - I added an update to my response

Yep - using dev_appserver.py revealed the issue. Apparently each HTTP request can be no larger than 32 MB. (found this thread). The average iMessage sqlite file is much bigger than that. Going to have to find some workaround... This thread recommends creating a one-off upload URL which uploads the file directly to GCS. Going to look into that. Thanks for the help!
